# Recommendation Model (students Recommended to a Job opening)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recommender-system, careers

I am currently working on a Recommendation Model. Which takes a Job Openings and Computer Science students and recommend students to the job. Which Model should I use or any suggestions you can give?
Students Have Following Features.
CGPA, Marks in 9 Technical Subjects, Skills rating in 10 different programming languages.
Jobs have 10 different programming language with rating in the language required for the Job. If a job is of python then 5 in python and 0s in all.
I have implemented a Neural Network.